# Открыть .jnlp с помощью javawebstart

Tags: java

Файл `.jnlp` хочу открыть при помощи `javawebstart`, выбираю `javaws`, но `javawebstart` не всплывает. Java установлена

Answer (score 1):

**Запуск приложения с помощью Java Web Start**

**С помощью браузера**

Нажмите на ссылку на веб-странице.

**С помощью значка на рабочем столе**

Если приложение используется часто, можно создать ярлык на рабочем столе или в меню 'Пуск'. В Java Web Start может отобразиться запрос на создание ярлыков или записи в меню 'Пуск'. Если выбран вариант 'Да', все последующие запуски приложения можно будет выполнять без браузера.

**С помощью средства просмотра кэша приложений Java**

Java Web Start также предоставляет средство просмотра кэша приложений, которое можно запустить на панели управления Java. Средство просмотра кэша приложения позволяет напрямую запускать загруженные приложения.

**Инструкции по запуску с помощью средства просмотра кэша приложений**

- Откройте меню Start (Пуск)
- Settings (Параметры)
- Control Panel (Панель управления)
- дважды щелкните на значке Java. На экране появится Панель управления Java.
- Перейдите на вкладку General (Общие)
- Нажмите кнопку View (Просмотр) в разделе Temporary Internet Files (Временные файлы Интернета)
- Выберите из списка приложение, которое предполагается запустить, и дважды щелкните на его имени
- Панель управления Java - просмотр приложений из кэша

**С помощью командной строки**

Чтобы запустить приложение с помощью командной строки, введите команду `javaws jnlp_url` где `jnlp_url` — URL-адрес jnlp-файла приложения.

- Выберите пункт меню Пуск > Выполнить > введите command

Отобразится интерфейс командной строки.
Введите `javaws url_of_jnlp`

[Источник](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/java_webstart.html)

Comment: Лучше всего из браузера.